# Translating Objective-C use of static and +(void)initialize to Swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, static

I am converting an old Objective-C class into Swift. My actual question is at the very end after all of the code.

Here is a cut-down version of the Objective-C class:

DateInfo.h:

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface RMYearInfo : NSObject

// There are also some instance properties but those aren't relevant to the question

+ (NSInteger)numberOfMonths;
+ (NSArray *)shortMonthNames;
+ (NSArray *)longMonthNames;
// several other class methods

@end
```

DateInfo.m:

```c
#import "DateInfo.h"

static NSArray *shortMonthNames = nil;
static NSArray *longMonthNames = nil;
// there are several other statics as well

@implementation DateInfo

+ (void)reinitialize {
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateFormatter *yearFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    shortMonthNames = [yearFormatter shortStandaloneMonthSymbols];
    longMonthNames = [yearFormatter standaloneMonthSymbols];

    // lots of other processing for the other statics
}

+ (void)initialize {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reinitialize) name:NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification object:nil];

    [self reinitialize];
}

+ (NSInteger)numberOfMonths {
    return shortMonthNames.count;
}

+ (NSArray *)shortMonthNames {
    return shortMonthNames;
}

+ (NSArray *)longMonthNames {
    return longMonthNames;
}

// Lots of other instance and class methods
```

As you can see, the `initialize` method sets up a notification handler so all of the static variables can be reinitialized if the locale is changed while the app is running.

Here is my Swift code. Since there is no `initialize` in Swift (any more), my solution is to use private backing variables for the public static variables.

```swift
import Foundation

public struct DateInfo {
    // some normal instance properties irrelevant to the question

    private static var _formatter: DateFormatter!
    private static var formatter: DateFormatter {
        if _formatter == nil {
            _formatter = DateFormatter()
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSLocale.currentLocaleDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
                _formatter = DateFormatter()
                _shortMonthNames = nil
                _longMonthNames = nil
                // reset all of the other statics as well
            }
        }

        return _formatter
    }

    private static var _shortMonthNames: [String]!
    public static var shortMonthNames: [String] {
        if _shortMonthNames == nil {
            _shortMonthNames = formatter.shortStandaloneMonthSymbols
        }

        return _shortMonthNames
    }

    private static var _longMonthNames: [String]!
    public static var longMonthNames: [String] {
        if _longMonthNames == nil {
            _longMonthNames = formatter.standaloneMonthSymbols
        }

        return _longMonthNames
    }

    public static var numberOfMonths: Int {
        return shortMonthNames.count
    }

    // lots of other similar private/public pairs of statics
}
```

Is this an appropriate way to translate the functionality given the need to be able to reinitialize the statics? I don't like having a private static backing each public static property.

Comment: There is an `init` in swift: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html

Comment: @muescha I'm not referring to `init`. I'm referring to the Objective-C class method `initialize` which Swift also had until Swift 3 (I think that's when it went away).

Comment: I don't find this objective-c method with Google in older swift releases

Comment: i just have no idea - can you help me: what is so different between the initialize and the init? Why you like to call an objective-c method in a pure swift implementation...

Comment: @muescha See [NSObject +load and +initialize - What do they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326435/nsobject-load-and-initialize-what-do-they-do) for an explanation of what the Objective-C `initialize` method does. See [Swift 3.1 deprecates initialize(). How can I achieve the same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42824541/swift-3-1-deprecates-initialize-how-can-i-achieve-the-same-thing) for a discussion about Swift eliminating the same method.

Comment: Thx for the links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some thoughts:

- Make `formatter` a static *stored* property (which are guaranteed to be lazily initialized only once). This  allows to get rid of the backing property `_formatter`.
- For more clarity, move the reinitialization code to a separate method, as in your Objective-C version.
- Do not cache the other static properties. For example, returning `formatter.shortStandaloneMonthSymbols` is only one indirection more than returning `_shortMonthNames`, but is simpler and allows to get rid of the remaining backing properties.
- A minor point: The notification closure does not access the `(notification)` argument, which can therefore be replaced by `_`.

Putting it together, we have the following implementation:

```
public struct DateInfo {

    private static func reinitialize() {
        formatter = DateFormatter()
    }

    private static var formatter: DateFormatter = {
        // This closure is executed exactly once, on the first accesss of the `formatter` property.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSLocale.currentLocaleDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in
            reinitialize()
        }
        return DateFormatter()
    }()

    public static var shortMonthNames: [String] {
        return formatter.shortStandaloneMonthSymbols
    }

    public static var longMonthNames: [String] {
        return formatter.standaloneMonthSymbols
    }

    public static var numberOfMonths: Int {
        return shortMonthNames.count
    }
}
```

---

Another option would be to use the typical [Singleton pattern](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/managing_a_shared_resource_using_a_singleton):

```
public class DateInfo {
    static let shared = DateInfo()

    private var formatter: DateFormatter

    private init() {
        formatter = DateFormatter()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSLocale.currentLocaleDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in
            self.formatter = DateFormatter()
        }
    }

    public var shortMonthNames: [String] {
        return formatter.shortStandaloneMonthSymbols
    }

    public var longMonthNames: [String] {
        return formatter.standaloneMonthSymbols
    }

    public var numberOfMonths: Int {
        return shortMonthNames.count
    }
}
```

The advantage is that all initialization is clearly done in the init method. A small disadvantage might be that more typing is needed to access the properties (e.g. `DateInfo.shared.shortMonthNames`).

Answer (score 3):

A few observations:

- I might suggest that we want to use stored properties, like the original Objective-C code. I would be wary of using computed properties that return collections, as that can introduce non-obvious performance hits if you reference this computed property repeatedly, causing the whole array to be re-retrieved multiple times. Admittedly, this collection is small enough, it’s unlikely to be material, but it is something to be sensitive to when dealing with computed properties and collections.
- I see no reason to store the `DateFormatter`. If you are using it for other purposes, then go ahead and do that, but there is nothing in this example that suggests that is the case.
- I’d personally go towards a singleton, too

Thus, perhaps something like:

```
class DateInfo {
    static let shared = DateInfo()

    private(set) var shortMonthNames: [String] = []
    private(set) var longMonthNames: [String] = []
    private(set) var numberOfMonths: Int = 0

    private init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSLocale.currentLocaleDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.update()
        }
        update()
    }

    private func update() {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        shortMonthNames = formatter.shortStandaloneMonthSymbols
        longMonthNames = formatter.standaloneMonthSymbols
        numberOfMonths = shortMonthNames.count
    }
}
```

And, if you have view controllers that are also observing `.currentLocaleDidChangeNotification`, you might want to eliminate any race conditions by introducing your own notification, e.g. `.dateInfoChanged`:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let dateInfoChanged = Notification.Name(rawValue: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".dateInfoChanged")
}
```

And then:

```
class DateInfo {
    static let shared = DateInfo()

    private(set) var shortMonthNames: [String] = []
    private(set) var longMonthNames: [String] = []
    private(set) var numberOfMonths: Int = 0

    private init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSLocale.currentLocaleDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.update()
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .dateInfoChanged, object: nil)
        }
        update()
    }

    private func update() {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        shortMonthNames = formatter.shortStandaloneMonthSymbols
        longMonthNames = formatter.standaloneMonthSymbols
        numberOfMonths = shortMonthNames.count
    }
}
```

Then view controllers can observe `.dateInfoChanged`, and you’ll be confident that they’ll be getting this month info after it was updated.

Comment: I like the suggestion about the custom notification. I haven't gotten far enough to actually test the locale changes yet but I can clearly see how this suggestion would be useful.